# Can anyone tell me what's the error in this code segment I even tried updating the project ID as said in the error and it also gave me an error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

```
gcloud iam roles update editor --project $DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID --file new-role-definition.yaml
                                
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.roles.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The name in the request (projects/qwiklabs-gcp-01-7bc9f94ad9bd/roles/editor) and the name in the role (projects/[PROJECT_ID]/roles/editor) must match.

gcloud iam roles update editor --project $DEVSHELL_qwiklabs-gcp-01-7bc9f94ad9bd --file new-role-definition.yaml              

ERROR: (gcloud.iam.roles.update) argument --project: expected one argument
Usage: gcloud iam roles update ROLE_ID (--organization=ORGANIZATION | --project=PROJECT_ID) [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --add-permissions | --description | --file | --help |
                         --organization | --permissions | --project |
                         --remove-permissions | --stage | --title
```

Comment: do you have $DEVSHELL_qwiklabs-gcp-01-7bc9f94ad9bd variable defined in your shell?

Comment: in your first command, there might be issue with the contents of your new-role-definition.yaml

Comment: Thanks @Narendra I made it work

Comment: I have added the info under answer section for more visibilty, upvote if you think it worked.

Answer (score 1):

`$DEVSHELL_qwiklabs-gcp-01-7bc9f94ad9bd` doesn't seem to be defined your shell?

```
gcloud iam roles update editor --project $DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID --file new-role-definition.yaml
```

*In your above command, look out for problems with the content of new-role-definition.yaml*

Answer (score 0):

Please empty your etag in the new-role-definition.yaml and change the [PROJECT_ID] to your id(qwiklabs-gcp-01-7bc9f94ad9bd)and update it using the command `gcloud iam roles update editor --project $DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID --file new-role-definition.yaml` in your cloudshell